# HttpListener how to serve images

Tags: c#, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I'm making a simple webserver to serve html, css, js & images (done in c#). I am using HttpListener and I can get the html, javascript and css files to work properly. I am just having trouble with the images. This is what I'm using currently:

```
        if (request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".png") || request.RawUrl.Contains(".ico") || request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".jpg") || request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".jpeg"))
        {
                string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                string[] img = request.RawUrl.Split('/');
                string path = dir + @"\public\imgs\" + img[img.Length - 1];

                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
                long numBytes = fileInfo.Length;

                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
                byte[] output = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
                binaryReader.Close();
                fileStream.Close();

                var temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output);
                return temp;
            }
```

I am converting the image into a string to return them (it's the way my boss suggested). This is the method where I am handling these requests.

```
private static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
```

This is my WebServer classes Run() method. The call to SetContentType just goes through the request.RawUrl and determines the content type.

```
public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StackLight Web Server is running...");

            try
            {
                while (_listener.IsListening)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                    {
                        var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;

                        try
                        {
                            // store html content in a byte array
                            string responderString = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);

                            // set the content type
                            ctx.Response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = SetContentType(ctx.Request.RawUrl);

                            byte[] buffer = buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responderString);


                            // this writes the html out from the byte array
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                            using(Stream stream = ctx.Response.OutputStream)
                            {
                                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ConfigLogger.Instance.LogCritical(LogCategory, ex);
                        }
                    }, _listener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ConfigLogger.Instance.LogCritical(LogCategory, ex); 
            }
        });
    }
```

My html page needs to display an image to the screen, it displays a broken image so far. I know the images directory is correct, I tested that.

This is where I got my code for the webserver: [here](https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx)

I was thinking that maybe I have to change the SendResponse method to not return a string

Comment: You can't arbitrarily decode an image file as a UTF8 string since the bytes of the file do not represent a UTF8 string. You can either (1) use `Convert.ToBase64()` and `Convert.FromBase64String()`, or the better option (2) don't use strings at all - return the `FileStream` instead, and use `CopyTo()` to send it directly to the response's output stream.

Comment: I figured that the problem was because I'm returning a string. So, I should change the return type of my function to FileStream?

Comment: I was able to get favicon.ico working, using convert.ToBase64() but the png I need to display still wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I created a class to hold the data, content type and the request.RawUrl. Then, where I was passing a string, I changed it to pass the object I created.

So, for my WebServer class, my Run method looks like this:

```
public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StackLight Web Server is running...");

            try
            {
                while (_listener.IsListening)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                    {
                        var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;

                        try
                        {
                            // set the content type
                            ctx.Response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = SetContentType(ctx.Request.RawUrl);
                            WebServerRequestData data = new WebServerRequestData();

                            // store html content in a byte array
                            data = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);

                            string res = "";
                            if(data.ContentType.Contains("text"))
                            {
                                char[] chars = new char[data.Content.Length/sizeof(char)];
                                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data.Content, 0, chars, 0, data.Content.Length);
                                res = new string(chars);
                                data.Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res);
                            }

                            // this writes the html out from the byte array
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = data.Content.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(data.Content, 0, data.Content.Length);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ConfigLogger.Instance.LogCritical(LogCategory, ex);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                        }
                    }, _listener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ConfigLogger.Instance.LogCritical(LogCategory, ex); 
            }
        });
    }
```

And my SendResponse method looks like this:

```
private static WebServerRequestData SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string[] fileUrl = request.RawUrl.Split('/');

        // routes
        if (request.RawUrl.Contains("/"))
        {
            // this is the main page ('/'), all other routes can be accessed from here (including css, js, & images)
            if (request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".png") || request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".ico") || request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".jpg") || request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(".jpeg"))
            {
                try
                {
                    string path = dir + Properties.Settings.Default.ImagesPath + fileUrl[fileUrl.Length - 1];

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
                    path = dir + @"\public\imgs\" + fileInfo.Name;

                    byte[] output = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

                    _data = new WebServerRequestData() {Content = output, ContentType = "image/png", RawUrl = request.RawUrl};
                    //var temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output);

                    //return Convert.ToBase64String(output);
                    return _data;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ConfigLogger.Instance.LogError(LogCategory, "File could not be read.");
                    ConfigLogger.Instance.LogCritical(LogCategory, ex);
                    _errorString = string.Format("<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>There was an error processing your request:<br />{0}</body></html>", ex.Message);
                    _byteData = new byte[_errorString.Length * sizeof(char)];
                    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(_errorString.ToCharArray(), 0, _byteData, 0, _byteData.Length);

                    _data = new WebServerRequestData() { Content = _byteData, ContentType = "text/html", RawUrl = request.RawUrl };
                    return _data;
                }
            }
```

I'm still cleaning up the code a bit but it now serves the images!

Oh... And here is the object I'm using:

```
public class WebServerRequestData
{
    public string RawUrl { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public string RawData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some really bad stuff here:

1. Empty catch. You'll never find out about many bugs.
2. Stuffing binary data into a string. Why? There's no encoding that is able to roundtrip binary data.
3. You're not disposing of `ctx`. I don't see why you need a manual finally block. Use `using`.
4. Untrusted callers can inject arbitrary paths into `path`. I could request your web.config file by navigating to `/img/..\..\web.config` (something like that).

Consider factoring out some common expressions into variables. You've got a Copy&Paste error with `ToLower`. Don't do dirty stuff and you'll have less bugs.

Comment: I fixed the empty catch and the disposing of ctx by using 'using'. How am I supposed to get my image to show up on my page though? I'm not sure how to do that. I also edited my question to reflect the changes. How could I prevent against injection (i guess that's a separate question)

Comment: What do I need to store the binary data? Someone suggested using Convert.ToBase64String() but that's still  a string.

Comment: what are the consequences of storing binary data in a string? It just means that I can't convert it to an image right? Should I just pass the byte array?

Comment: I was thinking that I should probably change the return type of my SendResponse method from string to an object that I'd create that stores a content type and the return data.

Comment: You want to pass and send bytes, so use a data structure that contains bytes. A byte[] for example, or a Stream (maybe a FileStream or a MemoryStream). Consider using File.ReadAllBytes.; Yes, using an object that encapsulates content and a content type is a good idea. That's good object oriented and functional design.